# using custom dataset for face recognition instead of MNIST

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I would like to use a custom dataset that contains image of faces for different person. I am planning to use the CNN and stacked-autoencoder to classify my image.

should i change (x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data() ?

or change the input_img , i think the problem is on the input data but i have no idea where it should be modified.

I'm lost i need help.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using`channels_first` image data format

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
 encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if 
using `channels_first` image data format
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if 
using `channels_first` image data format


from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
               epochs=50,
               batch_size=128,
               shuffle=True,
               validation_data=(x_test, x_test),
               callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')])

decoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(x_test)

n = 10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
for i in range(n):
# display original
ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i)
plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
plt.gray()
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

# display reconstruction
ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + n)
plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
plt.gray()
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change (x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data() with your data loader. You can use keras `ImageDataGenerator` class to accomplish this or build your [own](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly). If your image size is much larger than `28 x 28` you might need to change the model architecture as well because reshaping them directly to `28 x 28` won't produce good result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your dataset and split it into two subsets: `x_train` and `x_test`.

In which format is your data stored?

Comment: Thanks for your answer i want to work with my own jpg images so i can convert them to a matrix then i want to load them as dataset